# Adding to my TextView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-edittext

so I believe I am overthinking this but I want to double check.
I am getting my TextView from my EditText widget.

```
  addMileage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void OnClick(View v) {
  if (isErase) {
        nextMileage.setText(mileageInput.getText().toString());
  } else {
      nextMileage.setText("");
  }
  isErase = !isErase;
  }
```

How can I take what the user enters in the EditText then automatically take the number entered and + 3500. Then display in TextView?

Comment: addMileage is editext?or textview?

Comment: addMileage is the button

Comment: bit unclear with ur question

Comment: Sorry about that, new to stackoverflow. But my addMileage (Button) is OnCLickListener, thus sending input from EditText to TextView. I just want to add a number like 3500 to the string before it views in TextView.

Comment: ok got it use this --> int result=Integer.parseInt(mileageInput.getText().toString())+3500

Comment: and set text as nextMileage.setText(result+"");

Comment: yes thank you it worked. Boy I over thought that one. thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int result=Integer.parseInt(mileageInput.getText().toString())+3500;
nextMileage.setText(result+"");
```

Comment: what if the user has not entered anything in the EditText and press the button? Your solution doesn't work at that time. And many had given the same answer, so instead of posting the same answer, you would have up voted them. That is how SO works.

Comment: @Aniruddha u need to check with TextUtils.isempty function

Comment: And your answer is same as other peoples' answer. So you would have up voted rather than posting the same answer again.

Comment: @Aniruddha hmm , i was trying to expaion in comments but he wasnt undesrtandiny anyways

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

onClick

```
String s = your_editText.getText().toString();
if (!s.trim().equals("")
{
  int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
  int sum = i + 3500;
  your_textView.setText(" " + sum);
}
else
  your_textView.setText("Please enter the number");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code you have works (you didn't say it doesn't work), you can edit the `if` body as

```
if (isErase) {
    String mileageStr = (Integer.parseInt(mileageInput.getText().toString()) + 3500) + "";
    nextMileage.setText(mileageStr);
}
```

`Integer.parseInt()` allows you to convert a string to an integer quickly.

Comment: Yes it does works, it only does the input. Thanks I will try this.